# Diferença entre Integer.valueOf(String) e Integer.parseInt(String)

Tags: java, string, int

Preciso de converter uma `String` em `int`, e deparei me com estas duas opções, que têm um resultado igual.

- Existe alguma diferença entre elas?
- Existe alguma regra/convenção que diga qual usar ou é indiferente?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não há muita diferença.

Na verdade o `Integer.valueOf(String)` retorna um `new Integer(Integer.parseInt(String))`. então ele usa `Integer.parseInt(String)` dentro dele próprio.

Observando os codigos, o método `parseInt()` tem toda uma manipulação da String para erros, e variáveis incongruentes, enquanto o que o método `valueOf()` faz é `return Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s, 10));`.

Dentro do método super `valueOf()` é verificado se o valor passado é maior que -128, e menor que 127, se sim, o método busca em uma array, chamada de `cache` e localizada na classe `IntegerCache`, a sua posição e com o valor correspondente, que seria o mesmo, se não atender ao `if` é dado um retorno de um `new Integer(Integer)`.

Se um é melhor que o outro, não saberia dizer. Acredito que em questão de processamento o `valueOf()` seria melhor utilizado, enquanto em questão de rapidez de execução o `parseInt()` seria mais rápido. Eu prefiriria escolher o `valueOf()` como padrão, por questões de otimização.

Fonte:
[Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

**EDIÇÃO**:

Após um tempo, penso ser melhor anexar essa informação com a resposta oficial. Como dito pelo @Piovezan:

> Integer.parseInt() retorna um int (tipo primitivo) enquanto que Integer.valueOf() retorna um Integer (objeto wrapper imutável que "envolve" o tipo primitivo). A escolha vai depender do tipo de dado que você necessita (provavelmente na maioria dos casos vai ser Integer.parseInt()), lembrando que em operações repetitivas o boxing/unboxing (conversão de int para Integer e vice-versa) pode consumir um certo processamento.

Comment: Só para explicitar o que não ficou evidente na resposta:  `Integer.parseInt()` retorna um `int` (tipo primitivo) enquanto que `Integer.valueOf()` retorna um `Integer` (objeto _wrapper_ imutável que "envolve" o tipo primitivo). A escolha vai depender do tipo de dado que você necessita (provavelmente na maioria dos casos vai ser `Integer.parseInt()`), lembrando que em operações repetitivas o _boxing/unboxing_ (conversão de `int` para `Integer` e vice-versa) pode consumir um certo processamento.

Comment: Isso mesmo, não tinha atentado a isso.