# Converter String para inteiro em Java

Tags: java

Como faço para capturar uma *String* do usuário através do `Scanner` e transformar em inteiro?

Answer (score 16):

Faça algo assim:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine(); /* Vai pegar tudo até a primeira quebra de linha.
                              Garanta que o número é válido!
                           */
try {
       int i = Integer.parseInt(str); // Caso você queira tipo int, que é o usual.
       long l = Long.parseLong(str); /* É essencialmente a mesma coisa que o int, mas tem um
                                          limite de dados maior que o int, por consumir mais
                                          memória para a variável, e, por consequência um limite
                                          superior maior para o valor da variável.
                                       */
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  System.out.println("Numero com formato errado!");
} finally {
  s.close(); //fechar o Scanner para gerenciar melhor a memória.
}
```

Os outros dois tipos numéricos, `float` e `double` podem ser obtidos de uma `string` do mesmo modo, mas lembrando que essas funções separam as casas decimais com `'.'` e não com `','`!

Comment: Só tomar cuidado pra não tomar um `NumberFormatException` né?

Comment: Fato. Vou melhorar a resposta então hehe

Answer (score 10):

Além da função [`Integer.ParseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), [citado pelo mutley](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48847/6454), você também pode usar [`Integer.ValueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-):

```
public static int strToInt(String valor, int padrao) 
{
   try {
       return Integer.valueOf(valor); // Para retornar um Integer, use Integer.parseInt
   } 
   catch (NumberFormatException e) {  // Se houver erro na conversão, retorna o valor padrão
       return padrao;
   }
}
```

Para usar, faça assim:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int valor1 = strToInt("2015", 2015);
    int valor2 = strToInt("20iiii5", 2015);

    System.out.println(valor1); // 2015
    System.out.println(valor2); // 2015
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/JLBmIe)</kbd>

### Nota

Como mencionado pelo [Gustavo Cinque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48846/converter-string-para-inteiro-java/48853?noredirect=1#comment98786_48853), `Integer.valueOf` retorna um [tipo primitivo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), `int`, enquanto que `Integer.parseInt` retorna um [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), escolher entre um ou outro vai depender do propósito do código.

Veja mais informações nessa pergunta:

- [Diferença entre `Integer.valueOf(String)` e `Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43354/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-integer-valueofstring-e-integer-parseintstring)

Comment: Existe uma pequena diferença @QMechanic, o `.valueOf(str)` retorna um `int` enquanto o `Integer.parseInt(str)` retorna um `Integer`. [Fonte](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43354/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-integer-valueofstring-e-integer-parseintstring/43358#comment86122_43358)

Comment: **Quem votou contra:** Você pode comentar o que está errado no código ou o que posso fazer para melhorá-lo? O Espírito Cooperativo mandou abraços!!! :-S

Comment: Que susto meu amigo, achei que tinha sido eu que tinha votado contra, hehe.

Answer (score 7):

## Documentação

A primeira coisa importante para alguém que está começando a estudar ou trabalhar com Java é consultar a documentação das classes necessárias.

Por exemplo, [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) tem o método [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--), que seria a forma mais abreviada para resolver o problema de ler um inteiro. Lá na documentação, diz que a exceção `InputMismatchException` será lançada caso a entrada não seja um inteiro válido, portanto o programador pode tratar a exceção como melhor lhe convier.

Já [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) contém os métodos estáticos [`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) e [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-), os quais retornam o valor numérico de uma `String` como um primitivo (`int`) ou wrapper (`Integer`), respectivamente. O uso de cada um depende da finalidade do código.

## Usando `nextInt`

Com o `nextInt`, você pode ler diretamente inteiros da entrada já como números. Vários números podem ser lidos na mesma linha, desde que separados por espaços, por exemplo.

Entretanto devido à natureza da linha de comando, os números somente serão efetivamente lidos quando o usuário pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

### Exemplo

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
final int primeiroNumeroDigitado = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.format("Primeiro número digitado: %d%n", primeiroNumeroDigitado);
final int segundoNumeroDigitado = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.format("Segundo número digitado: %d%n", segundoNumeroDigitado);
scanner.nextLine();
```

Analisando linha a linha:

1. Cria um `Scanner` apontando para o input do programa, que geralmente tem como padrão o que o usuário digita na linha de comando.
2. Lê o primeiro inteiro. Neste ponto, geralmente o programa vai pausar e esperar o usuário digitar alguma coisa e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Ao receber a primeira linha digitada, o `nextInt` vai consumir os valores numéricos até encontrar algo que não seja um número, retornando então à execução normal.
3. Imprime o número digitado.
4. Lê o segundo número. Se houver caracteres não consumidos, o programa tenta ler os números ainda no *buffer* de entrada. Se encontrar a rotina retorna imediatamente, caso contrário o programa pausa novamente até receber outra entrada, como da primeira vez.
5. Imprime o segundo número digitado.
6. O método `nextLine` consome o restante da linha, limpando o `buffer` de entrada. Isto pode ser importante se o seu programa faz outras entrada depois, de forma a eliminar "sujeiras" que tenham sido digitadas por engano naquela linha.

Este programa pode receber entradas como:

> 10 20

Ou ainda:

> 10
>
> 20

E ambas vão imprimir os dois valores corretamente.

## Usando `parseInt` de forma inteligente

Algo chato quando você está testando em linha de comando é digitar algo errado no meio de um programa que lê vários dados do console e então ter que começar tudo novamente.

A fim de minimizar este problema, você pode implementar um método que tenta transformar a linha digitada em um número e, caso falhe, repita a operação até obter sucesso.

### Exemplo

```
public static int readInt(final Scanner scanner) {
    for (;;) {
        final String linhaDigitada = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            final int numeroInteiro = Integer.parseInt(linhaDigitada);
            return numeroInteiro;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Número inteiro inválido! Tente novamente.");
        }
    }
}
```

No código acima, temos que:

- O `for` gera um laço infinito, quebrado somente quando um número inteiro válido é digitado numa linha da entrada do `Scanner`. Claro que o programa pode ser interrompido como um todo, mas ele não continua normalmente sem atender tal condição.
- O método `nextLine` retorna a próxima linha digitada pelo usuário.
- O método `parseInt` tenta converter toda a linha para um inteiro. Note, aqui não é possível digitar dois números em uma linha.

  - Se o número for convertido para inteiro com sucesso, o método retorna o valor na próxima linha e encerra a execução.
  - Caso contrário, uma exceção `NumberFormatException` será lançada e o bloco `catch` será executado. Lá, a mensagem de que o número é inválido é impressa no console para avisar o usuário, tal bloco termina e o laço executa novamente esperando por um número válido

Finalmente, tal método pode ser chamado da seguinte forma:

```
final int terceiroNumeroDigitado = readInt(scanner);
System.out.format("Terceiro número digitado: %d%n", terceiroNumeroDigitado);
```

Este trecho reaproveita o `Scanner` do primeiro exemplo. A primeira linha chama o método e a segunda imprime o número digitado.

Um exemplo de interação:

> r
>
> Número inteiro inválido! Tente novamente.
>
> 3
>
> Terceiro número digitado: 3

## Código completo do exemplo

```
public class ScannerInputExample {

    public static int readInt(final Scanner scanner) {
        for (;;) {
            final String linhaDigitada = scanner.nextLine();
            try {
                final int numeroInteiro = Integer.parseInt(linhaDigitada);
                return numeroInteiro;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Número inteiro inválido! Tente novamente.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int primeiroNumeroDigitado = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.format("Primeiro número digitado: %d%n", primeiroNumeroDigitado);
        final int segundoNumeroDigitado = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.format("Segundo número digitado: %d%n", segundoNumeroDigitado);
        scanner.nextLine();

        final int terceiroNumeroDigitado = readInt(scanner);
        System.out.format("Terceiro número digitado: %d%n", terceiroNumeroDigitado);
    }

}
```

## Notas

> - Embora o Autor da Pergunta tenha explicitamente solicitado a leitura de uma `String` com posterior transformação, não creio ser um requisito rígido. Provavelmente foi uma forma de se expressar, portanto usar `nextInt` atinge o mesmo objetivo, porém fazendo tal "transformação" implicitamente.
> - O uso do `final` em variáveis e parâmetros pode parecer exagero, mas reforça a boa prática de não reusar variáveis e, principalmente para novatos, evita atribuições equivocadas como em `if (a = b)`.
> - Para entradas mais complexas, usar o `Scanner` a partir de um arquivo texto é mais interessante. Você gasta 5 minutos a mais preparando alguns arquivos, usa o [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) e pronto. Pense no tempo que vai economizar ao testar os vários cenários de um programa que está desenvolvendo.
> - Decidi adicionar esta resposta numa pergunta antiga, dado o alto número de visualizações e as respostas com poucas explicações ou más práticas.

Comment: +1 pela resposta, se pudesse teria dado um +1 extra por não ter jogado na duplicata nova (parece brincadeira, mas há quem o faça kkkk).

Comment: Ótima resposta! +1

Answer (score 4):

Só usar o `Integer.parseInt()`.

Exemplo:

```
String str = "123";
int valor;

valor = Integer.parseInt(str);
```