# Como converter uma String em inteiro?

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo

Como faço para converter um valor do tipo `string` que precisa ser armazenado em uma variável que é do tipo `int`? Aqui estão alguns códigos de conversão qual o mais apropriado para usar nessa conversão?

```
A.a = Integer.valueOf("10")
B.a = int.Parse("10")
C.a = Convert.Numeric("Macedo")
D.a = Convert.ToNumeric("10")
E.a = int.Convert.valueOf("Macedo")
```

Comment: Sua duvida não está nada clara e o código apresentado não faz muito sentido em relação a duvida. Por favor, edite a pergunta e seja mais especifico quanto a sua duvida e a relação com o código. Outra dica é sempre fornecer um **[mcve]** de código.

Comment: cezar, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Isto não é Java. Por favor, edite sua pergunta e adicione maiores informações sobre a linguagem, a versão que está utilizando e sobre o que está tentando fazer, afinal cada modo de conversão pode ter pontos fortes e fracos. Abraço!

Comment: Seria o que tem nessa pergunta aqui? [Converter string para inteiro Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48846/70)

Answer (score 2):

Java disponibiliza o seguinte método:

```
int one = Integer.parseInt("1"); // Retorna um tipo primitivo (int)
```

Este método recebe uma string e converte para um inteiro, tal como tu necessitas.

```
Integer one = oneInteger.valueOf("10"); // Retorna um Objecto Integer
int.parse("10"); // Não existe porque um tipo primitivo não pode ter métodos associados
```

Quanto aos restantes exemplos, esses métodos simplesmente não existem.