# Scanner dá erro se inverto a ordem em que os dados são lidos

Tags: java, scanner

Quando eu coloco para ler primeiro o `int` e depois as cadeia de `string`, o sistema funciona tranquilo, mas quando eu inverto ele dá um erro e não finaliza.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int idade, cont, maiorIdade;
        String nome, maisVelho;
        idade = 0;
        cont = 0;
        maiorIdade = 0;
        maisVelho = "a";

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (cont < 5){

            nome = ler.nextLine();
            idade = ler.nextInt();

            if ((nome != "a")&&(idade > maiorIdade)){
                maisVelho = nome;
                maiorIdade = idade;
            }
            cont++;
        }
        System.out.println(maisVelho);
    }
}
```

**Imagem descritiva:**

[image: Quando eu coloco para ler primeiro a idade e depois a string, o programa funciona, mas quando eu troco as posições de leitura aparece esse erro ai]

Comment: Só para avisar, comparar strings com operador não é uma boa, recomendo o uso do método equals da classe string.

Comment: Provavelmente o erro esta na hora de ler a idade, pois é esperado número e foi digitado texto. A ordem em que voce digita os dados deve ser a mesma ordem do preenchimento das variáveis.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos fazer alguns testes para ver o que acontece com cada leitura feita pelo [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), e assim entender porque "funciona" em alguns casos e em outros não.

---

Primeiro vamos ver o que acontece quando você lê o número antes do nome. Para entender melhor, coloquei um `System.out.println` para vermos o valor de cada variável logo depois que ela é lida pelo `Scanner`:

```
idade = ler.nextInt();
System.out.println("idade=" + idade);
nome = ler.nextLine();
System.out.println("nome=" + nome);
```

Se você digita `10 Fulano`, o que acontece é o seguinte:

- [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) lê o número 10
- [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) lê desde a posição em que parou anteriormente (ou seja, logo depois do `10`) até o final da linha

Por isso a saída é:

```
idade=10
nome= Fulano
```

Repare que o nome possui um espaço no início (antes do `F`), já que o `nextLine()` começa a leitura da posição em que parou (que é logo depois do `10`), e termina no final da linha.

---

Agora, se você inverter a ordem em que os dados são lidos:

```
nome = ler.nextLine();
System.out.println("nome=" + nome);
idade = ler.nextInt();
System.out.println("idade=" + idade);
```

Se você digita `Fulano 10`, a chamada de `nextLine()` vai pegar **toda a linha** (a variável `nome` terá toda a string `Fulano 10`) e o código vai imprimir:

```
nome=Fulano 10
```

Quando você digitar a próxima linha (por exemplo, `Ciclano 20`), o código tentará interpretá-la com `nextInt()`, mas como esta linha começa com `Ciclano` e isso não é um número, ocorrerá o `InputMismatchException`.

Você até pode trocar a chamada de `nextLine()` por [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--), que em vez de pegar a linha toda, pega somente até o espaço (que é o delimitador *default*, [segundo a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)):

```
nome = ler.next();
System.out.println("nome=" + nome);
idade = ler.nextInt();
System.out.println("idade=" + idade);
```

Agora se você digitar `Fulano 10`, o nome será "Fulano" e a idade será 10.

---

Mas a solução acima assume que o nome não tem espaços. Se você digitar `Fulano de Tal 10`, por exemplo, o `next()` só vai pegar `Fulano`, e o `nextInt()` tentará ler o trecho `de` como um número, e dará erro.

Nesse caso, talvez seja mais fácil ler a linha toda com `nextLine()`, fazer um [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) e ver se o número está no começo ou no fim (e depois considerar que o nome é o que sobrou).

Outro detalhe é que você não precisa comparar o nome do mais velho dentro do *loop*. Se quer saber a idade do mais velho, basta comparar as idades e depois você guarda o respectivo nome. No final fica assim:

```
int idade = 0;
int cont = 0;
int maiorIdade = -1;
String nome, maisVelho = "";

Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
while (cont < 5) {
    // divide a linha em partes, separadas por espaço
    String[] partes = ler.nextLine().split(" ");
    try {
        // ver se o número está no começo
        idade = Integer.parseInt(partes[0]);
        // juntar as partes restantes para compor o nome (do segundo ao último elemento)
        nome = String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(partes, 1, partes.length));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // número está no final
        idade = Integer.parseInt(partes[partes.length - 1]);
        // pegar do primeiro ao penúltimo elemento (juntar para obter o nome)
        nome = String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(partes, 0, partes.length - 1));
    }
    System.out.println("nome=" + nome);
    System.out.println("idade=" + idade);

    if (idade > maiorIdade) {
        maisVelho = nome;
        maiorIdade = idade;
    }
    cont++;
}
System.out.println("mais velho=" + maisVelho + ", idade=" + maiorIdade);
```

Agora tanto faz se a linha é digitada como `10 Fulano de Tal` ou `Ciclano da Silva 30`, pois o código tenta verificar o número no início, e se não der, verifica no final (e se não estiver no final, dará erro, que você pode escolher capturar colocando outro `try`/`catch`, se quiser).

Em seguida, o método [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) (disponível a partir do Java 8) junta as demais partes para formar o nome.

E o `if` que compara as idades não precisa comparar o nome, pois você só precisa verificar se nos novos dados digitados a idade é maior (e aí você seta o respectivo nome).

---

Uma outra alternativa, para o caso em que o nome vem primeiro e pode ter espaços, é mudar o separador *default* que o `Scanner` usa:

```
Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" (?=\\d)|\\n");
while (cont < 5) {
    nome = ler.next();
    idade = ler.nextInt();
... etc
```

Assim, o método `next` usa como separador a expressão regular indicada. No caso, ela possui um espaço (repare que há um espaço depois da abertura das aspas) e em seguida temos um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (o trecho `(?=\\d)`), que serve para verificar se algo existe depois da posição atual. Isso indica que eu uso como separador um espaço, desde que tenha um dígito (`\\d`) logo depois.

Mas a regex também usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`), indicando que também pode usar o `\n` (quebra de linha) como separador.

Ou seja, o método `next()` lê tudo até encontrar um espaço (desde que seja seguido de número) **ou** uma quebra de linha. Com isso, linhas como `Fulano de Tal 10` são lidas corretamente: primeiro o `next()` captura a string `Fulano de Tal` e em seguida `nextInt()` captura o `10`.

Mas se quiser uma solução mais genérica, em que tanto faz se o número vier no início ou no fim, melhor usar a solução anterior, com `split`.

Answer (score 0):

Listei aqui algumas mudanças que tive que fazer no seu código.

1. Nome de classe deve se iniciar com letra maiúscula.
2. Você pode declarar variáveis e inicia-las na mesma linha.
3. Adicionei alguns logs para indicar o que o código está pedindo.
4. Para leitura de strings ao invés de usar `nextLine()` pode usar somente o `next()`.
5. Comparação de strings em Java tem que ser feita através do método `equals`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int idade = 0, cont = 0, maiorIdade = 0;
        String nome = "", maisVelho = "";

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (cont < 5){
            System.out.print("Digite seu nome: ");
            nome = ler.next();

            System.out.print("Digite sua idade: ");
            idade = ler.nextInt();

            if (!nome.equals(maisVelho) && idade > maiorIdade) {
                maisVelho = nome;
                maiorIdade = idade;
            }

            cont++;
        }

        System.out.printf("O mais velho é %s com a idade de: %d\n", maisVelho, maiorIdade);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como citado nas outras respostas, existem alguns pontos que podem ser melhorados no seu código, mas para ser direto no seu problema:

Você não pode simplesmente alterar a ordem dos parâmetros, uma vez que você especifica a ordem das leituras (`nextLine` e `nextInt`).
Dessa forma, os parâmetros devem ser passados nessa ordem: `String` (para o `nextLine`) e `int` (para o `nextInt`).

Além disso, o uso do `nextLine` implica em levar o cursor de leitura para a próxima linha. Como se você fosse passar o nome e a idade em linhas diferentes.
Pelo o que entendi, não é isso o que vc quer, certo?
Dessa forma, use o `next()` ao invés do `nextLine()`.

---

Se ainda assim você quizer passar os parâmetros em ordens aleatórias, você deverá tratar o recebimento desses parâmetros.
Para fazer isso, você pode receber os dois através do método `next()` e nenhum pelo método `nextInt()` justamente pelo fato de não saber se o parâmetro que está sendo recebido é um valor inteiro ou não.
A partir daí, você precisa tentar identificar e converter esses dados (mas aí já é um outro *vasto* assunto)

---

Algumas referências:

- [Classe Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
- [Conversão de `String` em `int`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48846/converter-string-para-inteiro-em-java/48847)